# I am trying to find a function with specific criteria

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I am trying to find a function f(x) that more or less resembles the following when plotted on x=0..1 (not to scale):

[image: sample curve]

Criteria:

- f is a continuous and strictly non-decreasing (that is, the first derivative is not negative) function on the closed interval [0,1]
- f(0)=0, f(1)=1
- f' has exactly two distinct zeros on the closed interval [0,1]: 0 and 1
- f'' has exactly three distinct zeros on the closed interval [0,1]: 0, 1, and some given constant k between 0 and 1.
- $\int_{0}^{1}\!f \left( x \right) \,{\rm d}x$ = k

The plotted function above is one possible approximation for f(x) where k=1/2. For smaller values of k, the middle of the graph would be skewed downwards and to the right, for larger values of k it would be skewed upwards and to the left.

If it matters, the graph that I used to plot the above function was $y=x^3 \left( 6 x^2 - 15 x + 10 \right)$

EDIT: for clarification, there is no strict requirement that f(x) be a polynomial.  I am using the above polynomial as an example only to illustrate what I expect the curve to *GENERALLY* look like for a special case of k=1/2.   As I said, for different values of k, I would expect the middle part of the graph to be skewed either up and to the left or down and to the right, depending on if k is larger or smaller than 1/2, respectively.

Comment: The term "strictly non-decreasing" makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Clarification added.

Comment: Maybe think about $f'$ rather than $f$. It is some kind of density function which you can take to have value 0 at 0 and 1 (and 0 derivate there) with a single maximum at $x = k$.  Something like $x^2(1-x)^2(x-k)^2$.

Comment: if that is f', then that would mean that f' had a zero at k,    f' must have exactly two distinct zeros on [0,1],  0 and 1.  f'' needs to have a zero at k so that f' has  a local maximum at k.

Comment: f(x) has only one zero on the interval [0,1].  f' has two distinct zeros on the interval, f'' has three.

Comment: Sorry, maybe use p rather than k and take $p>1$ or $p<0$. Just experimenting with the form.

Comment: To build on your example, if you assume $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^5 a_i x^i$, you can plug in your constraints and try to derive the coefficients. I have not check if the problem is under-determined though.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to use a polynomial without creating the possibility of having an one or more extra zeros in the interval beyond the required number in f, f', or f''.

Comment: Well, my "solution" showed your polynomial is the only possible one that is 5th degree.  I'd try adding a 6th degree term and seeing where the logic takes you with the extra condition that the integral equals $k$

Comment: If I use a polynomial, I find that when I increase the degree of the polynomial to add more terms, and try to satisfy all the other constraints, I can end up having more zeros in the interval than what are desired in one or more of f, f', or f''

Comment: Does it have to be polynomial?  Can you do something with (say) $\frac{1 - \cos \pi f(x)}{2}$, where $f(x)$ goes "nicely" from $(0, 0)$ to $(1, 1)$?

Comment: There'd be a unique polynomial 6th degree that solves the endpoint conditions and the integral condition,  you might lose the number of 0s  or sign of $f'$,  otherwise yeah you'd have to use another function

Comment: I remember using functions like $$f(x)=\frac{x^{ab}}{x^{ab}+(1-x^{a})^{b}}$$ in the past, which have the general shape you're looking for (for some $a,b$) and fulfills your first few requirements. I don't see an easy way to make that formula controllable by a single parameter $k$, though. I'm just mentioning it because it could be worthy of investigation (by someone smarter than me, I'm afraid).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a general solution, but does show the limits of a 5th degree polynomial and gives an idea of where to try for other things

If you assume a 5th degree polynomial, the fact that $f,f',f''$ are all 0 at 0 tells us that it must be of the form $$f(x)=ax^5+bx^4+cx^3$$
so $$f'(x)=5ax^4+4bx^3+3cx^2$$
$$f''(x)=20ax^3+12bx^2 +6cx=3x(10ax^2+6bx+3c)$$
Plugging in $f(1)=0$ and $f'(1)=0=f''(1)$  gets us
$$a+b+c=1$$
$$5a+4b+3c=0$$
$$10a+6b+3c=0$$
Solving this gets us to $a=6,b=-15, c=10$
Plugging this into our $f'$ gets us
$$f'(x)=30x^4-60x^3+30x^2=30x^2(x-1)^2$$
so we have the required positive first derivative except at 0 and 1
likewise, plugging into $f''$ gets us to
$$f''(x)=2(60x^3-90x^2+30x)=60x(x-1)(2x-1)$$
which gets us to 0's at $0,1,\frac 1 2$, as required
Since there was nothing left for us to play with, the only possible $k$ that would work as a 5th degree polynomial would be the value of integrating this on $[0,1]$,  which gets us to
$$\frac 6 6 - \frac {15} 5 + \frac {10} 4=\frac 1 2$$

You would probably need to add a 6th degree term to give a free variable to solve for other values of $k$